# Apache SSL not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I've installed (from source) Apache 1.3 on a CentOS 5.2 and I'm trying to get SSL to work.

I used

> --enable-module=so

then added

> AddModule mod_so.c
>
> LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so

to httpd.conf.

Now I'm getting this error from configtest:

> Syntax error on line 44 of /www/conf/httpd.conf:
>
> Cannot load /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: ap_set_deprecated

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_ssl.so is making a a request for the symbol ap_set_deprecated which is not available with the 1.3 but with 2.0 (I just downloaded the sources and checked).

You'll need to rebuild mod_ssl.so. Download the sources here : http://www.modssl.org/source/mod_ssl-2.8.31-1.3.41.tar.gz . This doesn't make any calls to ap_set_deprecated. (I checked this too).

-- Ram

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing and matching versions willy nilly. Apache 1.3 needs to be patched to support SSL. You will need either Apache-SSL or Apache+EAPI patches and mod_ssl.

If you care about security, you should consider upgrading to Apache 2, which natively supports SSL and has a lot of security bug fixes.

I appreciate that it may be difficult to port your app to Apache 2, but it should be worth it in the long run.

Comment: It's a nightmare situation, I agree :(